# App rejected: strange iPhone crash log

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

Apple rejected my app two times due to a crash at launch. I have tested it many times on different devices (iPhone 4, iPhone3GS, Simulator, iPad2) and it never crashed.

EDIT: This is a part of the symbolicated crash log.

Thanks!

```
    Incident Identifier: DD9A5C38-DFE5-4CB5-A15B-8C55967FFFD1
        CrashReporter Key:   bf318d2d968114ff69d458c2f8cbdc6b869e1ec7
        Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
        Process:         iMetroRoma [2788]
        Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/8EC59E9D-D070-4CAD-892E-91BCE94AA58C/iMetroRoma.app/iMetroRoma
        Identifier:      iMetroRoma
        Version:         ??? (???)
        Code Type:       ARM (Native)
        Parent Process:  launchd [1]

    Date/Time:       2011-10-24 13:23:22.895 -0700
    OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
    Report Version:  104

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    0   CoreFoundation                  0x30d828bf __exceptionPreprocess + 163
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37f271e5 objc_exception_throw + 33
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x30ccbb6b -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 271
    3   iMetroRoma                      0x0000426f 0x1000 + 12911
    4   CoreLocation                    0x34fbc5df -[CLLocationManager onClientEventLocation:] + 1171
    5   CoreLocation                    0x34fbbf81 -[CLLocationManager onClientEvent:supportInfo:] + 201
    6   CoreLocation                    0x34fb662f __CLClientInvokeCallback_block_invoke_0 + 55
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x30d56b31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 13
    8   CoreFoundation                  0x30d5615f __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 159
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x30d55381 __CFRunLoopRun + 1433
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x30cd84dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
    11  CoreFoundation                  0x30cd83a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
    12  GraphicsServices                0x33906fed GSEventRunModal + 157
    13  UIKit                           0x32d4a743 UIApplicationMain + 1091
    14  iMetroRoma                      0x000024e3 0x1000 + 5347
    15  iMetroRoma                      0x0000249c 0x1000 + 5276


    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3206732c __pthread_kill + 8
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3655df54 pthread_kill + 48
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36556fe4 abort + 88
    3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x31a1ff64 abort_message + 40
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x31a1d346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37f272dc _objc_terminate + 140
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x31a1d3be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x31a1d44a std::terminate() + 14
    8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x31a1e81e __cxa_rethrow + 82
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37f2722e objc_exception_rethrow + 6
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x30cd853e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
    11  CoreFoundation                  0x30cd839e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
    12  GraphicsServices                0x33906fe6 GSEventRunModal + 150
    13  UIKit                           0x32d4a73c UIApplicationMain + 1084
    14  iMetroRoma                      0x000024dc 0x1000 + 5340
    15  iMetroRoma                      0x00002494 0x1000 + 5268
  ...

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
        r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
        r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3f54dce8      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fdffa6c
        r8: 0x001a1c20    r9: 0x31a20a4a     r10: 0x0000d224     r11: 0x0000cbfc
        ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdffa60      lr: 0x3655df5b      pc: 0x3206732c
      cpsr: 0x00000010

...
```

Comment: until you symbolicate the log, no-one can help. Import it in Xcode/Organiser/Devices/Device Logs

Comment: have you tried checking for zombie?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, did you "build and archive" when submitting to appstore?

If you did not, tough luck. There is not much you can do now. Even if you did Build and Archive, and lost the archive, you are out of luck.

If you did however, store the archive file of distribution build, very good!

Have you tried opening this in **XCode Organizer** (drag and drop the file onto organizer, it should try to symbolicate the crashlog). If not, do it.

When you do it, there are two possibilities:
Either the `iMetroRoma` functions will get symbolicated (meaning you'll see which line is crashing it) or it wont.

X*: If it does, you know where the application is crashing. Posting the details of that would help us solve the issue for you.

If it does not, then automatic symbolication in XCode is not working. Follow these steps (assuming you did all this from XCode 4):

1. From /Users/your_username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData remove
   all folders.
2. From /Users/your_username/Library/Application
       Support/iPhone Simulator remove all folders.
3. Clean your trash.

And then try deleting that crash log from XCode Organizer and drag/drop it again there. Possibly, it might symbolicate it now. If it does do step X*, If it does not, read on.

Now, you will need to do [follow the steps on this blog](http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/). (Very useful and well documented article).

Hopefully, it will symbolicate now and then move to step X*. If it does not, I'm sorry for not being able to help :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help. I tried to run symbolicatecrash from terminal, but i received this warning: ## Warning: Unable to symbolicate from required binary: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A334)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit

Comment: You do not have iOS SDK 5.0 yet?

Comment: I Have XCode 4.2 with iOS SDK 5.0

Comment: Are you sure its the release version and not a pre-release beta version of xcode/ios SDK?

Comment: I downloaded it from MAcAppStore. ps: Apple sent me 2 crashlogs, and i succesfully symbolicated one of them (I copied it on the question thread). It could be usefull?

Comment: It is definitely a crash in your code. Please follow the steps i mentioned to symbolicate it. (its not yet symbolicated... When symbolicated "iMetroRoma                      0x0000426f 0x1000 + 12911
" should show as "iMetroRoma [ClassName functionName:lineNumber]

Comment: The link to that blogpost is dead.

Answer (score 2):

According to the crash log, it looks like an array out of bounds exception. This means that you accessed an array with an index that doesn't exist. Unfortunately, the most important line (`3   iMetroRoma                      0x0000426f 0x1000 + 12911`
) is not symbolicated which means you have to go hunting for all your calls to `objectAtIndex:` and think about whether there's a possibility that an invalid index could be used.

Comment: What do you mean with "justification for this" ? See the exception stack trace, frames 3 to 1. The call flow is this: Frame 3: a method of his app (at address `0x1000 + 12911`) called Frame 2:`objectAtIndex:` on an object of type `__NSArrayM` which is an internal `NSArray` subclass. And `objectAtIndex:` in turn called Frame 1: `objc_exception_throw`. So the app called `[someArray objectAtIndex:something]`, and `objectAtIndex:` threw an exception. Usually this method only throws an exception when the index is out of bounds.